# PS3 Move not very responsive in The Fight

Tags: playstation-move, the-fight-lights-out

I have problem with this game, I can jab ok(no great, but ok) with a pad, but move is useless. When I throw strikes its like im trying to hit an angel. i need to aim down, but even then most strike doesnt count as strikes.

Any idea how to make PS3 Move be more responsive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read more [here](http://blog.us.playstation.com/2010/09/07/playstation-move-the-ultimate-faq/) but the gist is

1. Don't have any light sources directly opposite the camera. Light sources that flicker, or other TV etc. will affect performance.
2. You should be sufficiently far away from the camera. They recommend 5-9 feet, in my experience 6 feet is good.
3. Stuff should not be obstructing the camera and the camera should be pointed to the top half of your body. You should stand and play the game, if you sit and play, the system thinks you are a weird human body and does crazy stuff.
4. Contrast with the background. if you the color of the move controller blends in with the background, you will have problems.